# cannot convert "-1,37739,38739" to integer C#

Tags: c#, integer

I have tried to convert the string "-1,37739,38739" into an integer in order to pass the integer into a predefined method.

I'm getting System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

```
var dc1 = Convert.ToInt32(item.Path.ToString());
```

he item.Path come from a query value predefined as a string, I have to convert that string into an integer, it's coming with the above mentioned string value

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: what have you [***tried yourself***](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  also: try removing the commas, and try using long instead of int, since your input is [Too Large](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.int32.minvalue)

Comment: You should update the post with all the information needed, as @FranzGleichmann said. Not just post a comment underneath. The goal is to have a complete post where we don't need to search in the comments where are the other informations.

Comment: A number with 2 commas seems very odd to me.

Comment: Please show us more code, specifically what is `item`. The string that you show is not a valid number in any form.

Answer (score 1):

`-1,37739,38739` is - reformatted - `-13,773,938,739`; `int.MinValue` (the most negative value a 32-bit signed integer can represent) is `-2,147,483,648` - so: it won't fit. Try `long` instead of `int`, i.e. `ToInt64`.

You may also need to specify an explicit culture (depending on your locale), and be a little more... *forgiving* re group separators:

```cs
if (long.TryParse("-1,37739,38739",
    NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var val))
{
    Console.WriteLine(val); // works
}
```

Comment: im getting the same error System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: @Phil maybe just take out the commas, if they are intended as group separators? what is your locale? in many locales, comma means "decimal point", so two commas is bad, and a comma in an integer is bad

Comment: @Phil see also: update

Answer (score 0):

This not a surprise.
1st : -1,37739,38739 is not properly formatted. This should be either
-13773938739
or
-13,773,938,739 (or -13 773 938 739 depending on your locale)
2nd: Int32 is an integer based on 32 bits which gives min and max values -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647

See documentation here [Int32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=net-6.0)

If you want to convert a string which is not controlled upfront, then I would suggest you "clean" it

```
        string item = "-1,37739,38739";
        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
        item = rgx.Replace(item, "");
```

and maybe convert to Int64

```
var dc1 = Convert.ToInt64(item);
```

If you want to avoid exception, you also can try to parse the string (once cleaned)

```
if (Int64.TryParse(item, out var dc1))
{
    // doSomething
}
else
{
    //  handle error
}
```

Comment: What is the solution, any code suggestion? this is the given value from my data source

Comment: You had a "code suggestion" in the second answer of your post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71676624/10458514

Comment: thanks, or can i at least get this value from "-1,37739,38739" to -1.37739.38739, the tricky part is i have to use it as an integer as it is?, if its possible

Comment: I don't really get it. Can you give more inputs regarding WHY you get this value in a format which is NOT a numeric format ?
Are those ',' always separating groups of 5 digits ?

Comment: yes, this is the same value that i have to return as an integer using a pre defined method that i cannot change, im receiving this value as a string

Comment: You need to return an integer ? 
Then I don't see why the code I gave is not fulfilling your expectations.
You receive item.Path.ToString()
Then 
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
var cleanedStringToConvert =  rgx.Replace(item.Path.ToString(), "");
if (Int64.TryParse(cleanedStringToConvert, out var dc1))
{
    return dc1;
}
else
{
    //  handle error
    throw new Exception($"{cleanedStringToConvert} is not a Int64")
}

Comment: Please, provide more code around this need so I can understand better the context (eg. the call class where you need to convert or at least the complete method)

Answer (score -1):

string **item** = "-1,37739,38739";
var **munyamatindike**=Convert.ToInt32(item);

the above code snippet should fix the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9asj.png)